# Visual Studio 2015 + TypeScript 1.6.3 + JQuery

Tags: jquery, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.6

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, and I have a project that uses Typescript 1.6.3 and JQuery.
The problem is that the

`JQuery.data(key: string): any;`

function should return any, but if I have a `JQuery` variable named "element" and I write:

`element.data('field')`

the Intellisense keeps saying the function returns `JQuery` instead of `any`. Also, it says the currently used overload is

`JQuery.data(obj: { [key: string]: any; }): JQuery;`

and not the one that accepts a simple string.

Am I missing something or is it known bug?

Comment: I have same problem too.. Can you slove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get an up-to-date version of jquery.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped. There was a change in the TypeScript compiler (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4619) that exposed an incorrect definition in the .d.ts file.